# Image not inside circle avatar

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

i'm trying to pick image from my gallery then show it to my circleavater, the problem is, the image isn't inside the circle avatar.

So, i'm using `image_picker: ^0.4.12+1`

```
  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

and here is the widget

```
  children: <Widget>[
                _image == null ?
                 Container(
                    width: 150.0,
                    height: 150.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, bottom: 10.0),
                     child: CircleAvatar(
                       radius: 30.0,
                       backgroundImage:
                       NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                     )
                ): Container(
                  height: 150.0,
                  width: 150.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, bottom: 10.0),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 30.0,
                      backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      child:  new Image.file(_image),
                    )

                )
//etc
```

here is the screenshot when the page open

[image]

and here is the screenshot after i pick an image

[image]

how can i fix it, sorry for my english and thanks in advance

Comment: you have to give - `Image.file(_image)`, to `backgroundImage:` not to child

Comment: thanks, but i already try that. It give me an error. type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

Comment: Do `FileImage(_image)` - `backgroundImage: FileImage(_image)`

Comment: ahh, it is working. i wonder why child is not working

Comment: `child` basically overlay it on top. we have to clip it manually if we want to use child.

Answer (score 0):

Replace CircleAvatar with clipoval and your image get fixed in container.

```
Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
              ),
              child: ClipOval(
                child:  NetworkImage('https://via.placeholder.com/150'),
              ),
            ),
```